# Why does my bash script print colon at end of loop?

Tags: bash

I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

num_loops=3

for i in `seq $num_loops`:
do
    printf 'Iteration %s\n' $i
done
```

And when I run it, I get the following output.

```
$ ./loop-test.sh
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
Iteration 3:
```

I'm wondering why the script generates an extraneous colon (":") at the end of the final iteration? I know that the variable 'i' is a string, but why would the last iteration in the 'seq' command append the colon?

Comment: maybe you wanted to use `;`, which can be omitted.

Comment: Because Bash is not Python ;-) Just delete the colon.

Answer (score 11):

Because you're telling it to use one:

```
for i in `seq $num_loops`:
                         ^---
```

The `:` is not necessary, and becomes part of the command line arguments:

```
for i in 1 2 3:
```

at the final iteration, `$i = '3:'`, basically.

Comment: That's it! So if you do `echo $(seq 3):` you get `1 2 3:`

Comment: Ah crap. First time Python has bit me in the tail!